# How do i solve two coupled nonlinear PDEs through Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, physics, boundary-conditions

these are two relativistic fluid governing equations,
∂_t (γe)+∂_x(γev)=0
γ∂_t(γv)+∂_x[(γv)^2/2]=-(C/(1+C))*∂_x[log(e)]
where `γ=1/sqrt(1-v^2)` is Lorentz factor, `v=v(x,t)` is three velocity, `e=e(x,t)` is energy density, `C` is a parameter.

Initial condition

```
v[x,0]=0.5
e[x,0]=sech(2x)+1
```

Boundary condition:
periodic boundary condition, but I don't konw what it is.
I use mathematica solve these equations numerically, here is the code

```
\[Gamma] = 1/(1 - (v[x, t])^2)^0.5；
pde = {D[\[Gamma] e[x, t], t] + D[\[Gamma] e[x, t] v[x, t], x] == 0,
\[Gamma]D[\[Gamma] v[x, t], t] + D[0.5 (\[Gamma] v[x, t])^2, x] + 
     C D[Log[e[x, t]], x]/(1 + C) == 0};
ic = {v[x, 0] == 0.5, e[x, 0] == Sech[2 x] + 1, C == 1/3};
bc = {v[-1, t] == 0.5, v[1, t] == 0.5, e[-1, t] == Sec[-2] + 1, 
e[1, t] == Sec[2] + 1};
sol = NDSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, {v, e}, {x, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

My question is the boundary condition, how to set it, and I am not sure my code is right.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnnEu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYlDw.png)

Comment: There are inconsistent conditions: `e[x, 0] == Sech[2 x] + 1` and `e[-1, t] == Sec[-2] + 1,` Maybe this is a typo `Sec`  instead of `Sech`

Comment: initial eqaution is sech, which ensures the energy is concentrated whtin a range, the bc is periodic, but the specific form has not been given in paper,

Comment: @zhiweimin Could you give a link to the paper?

Comment: You need to specify `c` (`C` is a reserved symbol) at the beginning of the computation.  Also, `\[Gamma]D[\[Gamma]` should be `\[Gamma] D[\[Gamma]`.  With these changes, your code produces results, although with warning messages.

Comment: Use `bc = {v[-1, t] == v[1, t], e[-1, t] == e[1, t]}` to set periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: Here is the link for this paper,and the equation is in chapter 4.1 http://mathreview.uwaterloo.ca/archive/voli/2/olsthoorn.pdf